# Showing vector layers through multiple select using OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers

I am using OpenLayers 6.

I need to show/hide layers on a map, by using a multiple select. The multiple select generates an array which should be matched with the layers on the map. These are grouped in a second array.

```
var region_selected = ["Area 1", "Area 2", "Area 3"]

(function($) {
for (k = 0; k < region_selected.length; ++k){
    var reg = region_selected[k];

    for (i = 0; i < layers_group.length; ++i){
      var layer_region = layers_group[i].get('name');

      if(reg === layer_region){
        layers_group[i].setVisible(true);
      }  
      else {
        layers_group[i].setVisible(false);
      }
    }
  }
});
```

The result is that the last element of the array `region_selected` is visible, because when one condition is true for the first iteration, then it is no more true for the second iteration and so on.

Since I have this problem also with the layer's features, is there a solution?

**A POSSIBLE SOLUTION**

I found a solution by setting all layers invisible when the multiple select is triggered. I don't know if there are better solutions. This however works, and I added the possibility of select "all" layers together.

```
(function($) {
var j;
for (j = 0; j < layers_group.length; ++j){
  layers_group[j].setVisible(false);
  };

for (k = 0; k < region_selected.length; ++k){
    var reg = region_selected[k];
    if (reg == "all") {
      for (y = 0; y < layers_group.length; ++y){
        layers_group[y].setVisible(true);
        };
    }
    else {
      for (i = 0; i < layers_group.length; ++i){
        var layer_region = layers_group[i].get('name');
        if(reg === layer_region){
          layers_group[i].setVisible(true);
        }  
      }
    }
  }
```

});

Comment: What would be criteria for the "better"? If your solution works as desired, why would you want something "better"?

Comment: @ TomazicM my criteria for "better" are basically to avoid redundancy in my script.  But yes you are right, given that the above works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's always nice to try to make code "better", that's how you learn.
If you want something "better" just do one loop over your layers_group and use more native array functions.

```
layers_group.forEach((group)=> {
  const name = group.get('name');
  const visible = region_selected.includes('all') || region_selected.includes(name);
  group.setVisible(visible);
};
```

I didn't test the code. ;)

Comment: Thanks @oterral, you code seems working and it is much compact than mine.